# Searching two tables to get a particular matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have two tables one contain the columns (name,price,extra), the other contains the columns (name, price, category).

I also have a select field that contain all the items in the name column from the two tables (which I used a union clause to do).

Now I want to be able to search the two tables and get the price of t from any of the table when any of the item from the select field is choose. I am using ajax to do the dynamic selection. I do not know where to start or what to do. I need an idea from anybody on how to achieve this.

I do not have any idea on how to go about this

Comment: I would start by writing some queries.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
SELECT name, price 
FROM (SELECT name,price FROM tableA 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT name,price FROM tableB) AS A 
WHERE name LIKE '%abc%';
```

Comment: `union all` would be much more efficient.

Comment: Saharah i have used your suggestion but it gives me an error of unknow column name in field list don't know why

Comment: i finally got it working <br>$item = $_GET['q'];
 $search_query ="select name,price from (select name,price from foods union all select name,price from drinks) as iPrice where name like '%$item%'";
 $res = mysql_query($search_query) or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
 echo $row['price'];

Comment: This is the same query which i had answered and do not forget to accept any one answer from all answers which is useful to you